# Trying to make a javascript program for creating an account

Tags: javascript

The requirement is : "If the registration cannot be performed successfully, you will be able to display this error message you want. Instead, if all the conditions are met, you must hide all the elements on the page related to the registration and display in the accessory place any message you want."

And this is what i've done in javascript, but let me explain to you. When i'm trying to see if the conditions are correct, for example i put "123456789" to password and "12345678" to confirm password. An error will appear, "both password must match" and the error stays there even when i'm completing the right password for these 2 labels (for password-123456789 and confirm password-123456789). What i should do to hide that error?

```js
        let btn=document.getElementById('register-button');
    let divsucc=document.getElementById('success-message');
    let diverr=document.getElementById('error-message');
    let username=document.getElementById('username');
    let password=document.getElementById('password');
    let confirmpassword=document.getElementById('confirm-password');
    let usernamediv=document.getElementById('username-div');
    let passworddiv=document.getElementById('password-div');
    let confirmpassworddiv=document.getElementById('confirm-password-div');
    let btndiv=document.getElementById('register-button-div')
    btn.onclick=function(){
        if(password.value.length<=8 && username.value.length==0 || password.value.length>=8 && username.value.length==0){
            diverr.innerHTML="Enter your username";
        }
        else if(username.value.length>0 && password.value.length==0){
            diverr.innerHTML="Enter your password";
        }
        else if(confirmpassword.value.length==0){
            diverr.innerHTML="Confirm your password";
        }
        else if(password.value!=confirmpassword.value){
            diverr.innerHTML="Both passwords must match";
        }
        else if(password.value.length<8){
            diverr.innerHTML="Password must be at least 8 characters";
        }
        else if(username.value.length>0 && password.value.length>=8 && password.value===confirmpassword.value){
            usernamediv=usernamediv.style.visibility='hidden';
            passworddiv=passworddiv.style.visibility='hidden';
            confirmpassworddiv=confirmpassworddiv.style.visibility='hidden';
            btndiv.style.visibility='hidden';
            divsucc.innerHTML="Account created!";
        }
    }
```

```html
<html>
    <body>
        <h1>Create an account</h1>
        <div id="error-message"></div>
        <div id="success-message"></div>
        <div id="username-div">
            Username: <input id="username">
        </div>
        <br>
        <div id="password-div">
            Password: <input type="password" id="password">
            Must be at least 8 characters
        </div>
        <br>
        <div id="confirm-password-div">
            Confirm password: <input type="password" id="confirm-password">
            Both passwords must match
        </div>
        <br>
        <div id="register-button-div">
            <button id="register-button">Register now</button>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If displaying the error occurs by setting text here:

```
diverr.innerHTML="Both passwords must match";
```

Then presumably you can hide the error by setting that same text to an empty value:

```
diverr.innerHTML="";
```

You can do this in response to anything you like.  For example, if you want the error to disappear when the button is clicked then simply make that the first line of your click handler function:

```
btn.onclick=function(){
  diverr.innerHTML="";
  // the rest of the function
}
```

Comment: i tried this before, i am at a course where they have their editors and when i press on verify the code, it say that my code doesn't resolve the problem correctly. and i don't know where is the problem, or what is the problem.

Comment: @programmerjavascript: In what way does it "not resolve the problem correctly"?  When you try it, does it not work in some way?  If you have an instructor who is looking for a *specific* solution and not just any working solution then that isn't really something we can help with.

Comment: i tried in multiple ways to test the program, but i can t figure it out if the program is correct or not,that s why i asked here. can you make the proggram by yourself to try and send it to me ?
the requirement is :
If the registration cannot be performed successfully, you will be able to display this error message you want. Instead, if all the conditions are met, you must hide all the elements on the page related to the registration and display in the accessory place any message you want

Comment: @programmerjavascript: I've updated your question to be a runnable code snippet.  You can use this to observe how your code works.  (And as part of your development and debugging you *really should* have a way to actually execute and observe your code.  You can't just write code and hope for the best, you need to *test* it.)  When you modify this code to use this suggestion, in what observable way does this not work as expected?

Comment: i have editor. i saw my code, i didn t wrote it and hope for the best, but when i trying to verify it in my course editor it shows me like this : "Your code does not solve the problem correctly. Try again until you succeed!"
i don t know what i'm doing wrong. i mean sorry this is not a course, my main language is not english. this is a challenge, i dont have support

Comment: @programmerjavascript: *"i can t figure it out if the program is correct or not"* - This implied otherwise.  It seems like there are **two** issues here.  One is whether or not your code does what you want it to do.  That we can help with.  When you test your code, does it do what you want it to do?  The other issue is whether or not what you want your code to do matches what your instructor (human or automated) expects.  That we can only guess.  Unless you have insights otherwise, what your code does (with this change) appears to do what I would expect.

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't found the solution, try this. Instead, if you found the solution, please post it here.

```
<script>
    var username = document.getElementById('username');
    var password = document.getElementById('password');
    var confirmPassword = document.getElementById('confirm-password');
    var button = document.getElementById('register-button');
    var errorMessage = document.getElementById('error-message');
    var succesMessage = document.getElementById('success-message');
    button.onclick = function passwordValidation() {
        if(username.value == "") {
            errorMessage.innerHTML = "Enter username";
        } else if(username.value != "" && password.value == "") {
            errorMessage.innerHTML = "Enter password";
        } else if(username.value != "" && password.value != "" && password.value.length <8) {
            errorMessage.innerHTML = "Password must be at least 8 characters";
        } else if(username.value != "" && password.value != "" && password.value.length >= 8 && confirmPassword.value == "") {
            errorMessage.innerHTML = "Confirm password";
        } else if(username.value != "" && password.value != "" && password.value.length >= 8 && confirmPassword.value != "" && confirmPassword.value != password.value) {
            errorMessage.innerHTML = "Both passwords must match";
        } else {
            document.getElementById('username-div').hidden = true;
            document.getElementById('password-div').hidden = true;
            document.getElementById('confirm-password-div').hidden = true;
            document.getElementById('register-button-div').hidden = true;
            errorMessage.innerHTML = ""; 
            succesMessage.innerHTML = "Congratulations! Account successfully created!";
        }
    }
</script>
```